# flip effect on changing scene Unity3d 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, flip, scene, tween

I want to add a flip effect for changing my scene and if its not possible , flip effect with in a scene. Attached is the reference video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXRKJRL0TDU

Comment: Please post some code with what you've tried. SO isn't a give-me-free-code forum, it's a place you can get your code fixed

Comment: With due respect @VenkatatAxiomStudios , if you dont have any solution please dont comment. You are just wasting yours as well as mine time.

Comment: If you plan on using a forum, least you can do is follow its rules. You can't do that, but the least you can do is not turn around and make even more comments when you are asked to do so.

Comment: I know what is forum and why we use that, I simply had a problem and want to know better way to implement it. This forum is not restricted to coding. There is no such rule to provide coding for all your problem, Please be more aware before creating nuisance and killing time. @VenkatatAxiomStudios

Answer (score 0):

Without trying it myself i would suggest you to play around with
 rendertextures 
to get the current view on a plane - then rotate the plane 90 degrees 
- then load the new scene wich also has a plane wich alredy is rotated and has a texture of the scene applied
- then make that plane rotate 90 degrees so its facing the camera 
- then switch to the main camera (wich also would provide the rendertexture)

Comment: I will surely try it.